# Dropwizard ExceptionMapper: Validate original header fields

Tags: dropwizard

Does anyone know how I can get the original header fields from request? I would like to validate, if client will receive html or just plain/text response. Can I get this fields inside 'toResponse' method of exceptionMapper?

I created exceptionMapper like in this post:
http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/

Comment: I ended up to create Filters ...  -> https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#jersey-filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did want to get information from the original request object, you can add the following to your controller.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@Path("/my")
@Produces(["application/json", "application/hal+json"])
class MyController {

  @Context
  protected HttpServletRequest httpRequest

  @Timed
  @GET
  public Response getOne(){
    httpRequest.getHeaders(); 
    ... //do something with headers
    return Response.ok(new Person(id:1), httpRequest.getContentType());
  }
```

Comment: Ah this works also in the exception Mapper. This is funny, because I thought I have tested it ...