# Java: Get body out of HttpContext?

Tags: java, http, jersey, dropwizard

The problem:

All I have is the HttpContext context from interface com.sun.jersey.api.core.HttpContext.

What I need:

String entityBodyMd5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(requestBody);

I use Dropwizard and I have an Provider class implementing the InjectableProvider interface, but I'm not able to get the md5Hex value. Any ideas?

Perhaps it would be possible to get the HttpServletRequest out of HttpContex, so I can get the Inputstream.  If you have any idea ... let me know :-)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282323/dropwizard-exceptionmapper-validate-original-header-fields): you can inject the `HttpServletRequest` using @Context (import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;) annotation

Answer (score 1):

As there isn't much information about the context, I could only check the code `com.sun.jersey.api.core.HttpContext`. And it looks like this should give you the request body:

```
String requestBody = context.getRequest().getEntity(String.class);
```